# copying data from a folder of workbooks into a single worksheet iteration through loop in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy data from a couple of workbooks present in a folder into a single workbook. I am looping through the folder to fetch the data from the various workbooks but I need to paste the data spanning from A5:D5 in loop. 
i.e A5:D5 in the destination sheet is one workbook's data in the folder, I need the other set of data to be copied into A6:D6 and so on for the number of workbooks in the folder. Please help me loop through this.

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim Filename As String
    Dim Path As String
    Path = "D:\Macro_Demo\estimation_sheets\"
    Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls")
    Set target = Workbooks.Open("D:\Macro_Demo\Metrics_Macro_dest")
    '--------------------------------------------
    'OPEN EXCEL FILES
     Do While Len(Filename) > 0  'IF NEXT FILE EXISTS THEN
     Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Path & Filename)
      target.Sheets("Metrics_Data").Range("A5").Value = wbk.Sheets("summary").Range("I5").Value
     target.Sheets("Metrics_Data").Range("B5").Value = wbk.Sheets("summary").Range("I6").Value + wbk.Sheets("summary").Range("I7")
     target.Sheets("Metrics_Data").Range("C5").Value = wbk.Sheets("summary").Range("I8").Value
     target.Sheets("Metrics_Data").Range("D5").Value = wbk.Sheets("summary").Range("I9").Value
      MsgBox Filename & " has opened"
      wbk.Close True
      Filename = Dir
      Loop

      MsgBox "Task complete!"
      End Sub
```

Comment: What is the specific issue you are facing?

Comment: You need to be more specific about your issue. I don't see a question here. Does it do nothing? Are you getting an error? Are the results not what you expected? ...

Comment: I am unable to figure how I can achieve this specific loop through the columns.This piece of code works perfectly fine, but only the data in the last sheet of the folder is getting copied, other data is just getting overwritten because I have hardcoded the columns A5 to D5

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim wbk As Workbook, target As Workbook, excelFile As String, path As String, rw As Integer

    path = "D:\Macro_Demo\estimation_sheets\"
    excelFile = Dir(path & "*.xls")
    rw = 5

    Set target = Workbooks.Open("D:\Macro_Demo\Metrics_Macro_dest")

    Do While excelFile <> ""
        Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(path & excelFile)

        With target.Sheets("Metrics_Data")
            .Range("A" & rw) = wbk.Sheets("summary").Range("I5")
            .Range("B" & rw) = wbk.Sheets("summary").Range("I6") + wbk.Sheets("summary").Range("I7")
            .Range("C" & rw) = wbk.Sheets("summary").Range("I8")
            .Range("D" & rw) = wbk.Sheets("summary").Range("I9")
        End With

        wbk.Close True

        rw = rw + 1
        excelFile = Dir
    Loop

    MsgBox "Task complete!"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the next available row on your destination sheet, store that in a variable, and write the data relative to that cell.  Like this

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim shSource As Worksheet, shDest As Worksheet
    Dim sFile As String
    Dim rNextRow As Range

    Const sPATH As String = "D:\Macro_Demo\estimation_sheets\"

    'Open the destination workbook
    Set shDest = Workbooks.Open("D:\Macro_Demo\Metrics_Macro_dest.xls").Worksheets("Metrics_Data")

    sFile = Dir(sPATH & "*.xls")

    Do While Len(sFile) > 0
        Set shSource = Workbooks.Open(sPATH & sFile).Worksheets("summary")

        'start at row 1000 and go up until you find something
        'then go down one row
        Set rNextRow = shDest.Cells(1000, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

        'Write the values relative to rNextRow
        With rNextRow
            .Value = shSource.Range("I5").Value
            .Offset(0, 1).Value = shSource.Range("I6").Value
            .Offset(0, 2).Value = shSource.Range("I8").Value
            .Offset(0, 3).Value = shSource.Range("I9").Value
        End With

        'Close the source
        shSource.Parent.Close False

        sFile = Dir
    Loop

    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Kusleika, for the detailed explanation...!